# Project Euler #1, getting higher results for no apparent reason

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem with the first coding challenge on the Project Euler website. This is what you have to do:

> "If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3
>   or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000."

Here's my code (c#):

```
total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= (999 - (999 % 3)) / 3; i++)
{
    total += 3 * i;
}

for (int i = 0; i <= (999 - (999 % 5)) / 5; i++)
{
    total += 5 * i;
}
```

When I return total it gives me '266333' while it should be '233168'. I've been staring at it for about an hour and I have no clue where my code is going wrong. Sorry if this is a stupid question but google isn't helping me and I feel really dumb.

Comment: It's larger because numbers like `15` are being added twice.

Comment: Oh my god of course. thank you

Comment: By the way, `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3) total += i;` would be a little more efficient than your current loop, though this approach is ultimately flawed since you need to avoid duplicating terms.

Comment: **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: It's great that you got a solution, but now take a step back and ask yourself "how could I have come to that solution without asking for help?"  A great technique is to work a smaller example; suppose instead you tried to sum the multiples of 3 or 5 below 20; you can work out the correct answer by hand in less than a minute, and you would get a wrong answer with your algorithm. It would be wrong by 15, and you would instantly know what the problem was. Many Project Euler problems are amenable to this technique; many of them give you "small" versions of the problem for just that reason.

Comment: While we are looking at your code -- it is weird. Can you say why you computed `(999 - (999 % 5)) / 5` instead of computing `999/5` ?  The fact that you believed this was necessary indicates that you may have a false belief about how arithmetic works in C#, and having that false belief will lead to poor results in future PE problems.

Comment: Just a thought - If you're going through these exercises, this would be an awesome opportunity to practice unit tests. You could write your method to take `maxNumber` as an argument. Then write a unit test that asserts that if maxNumber is 20, the result is 98. Write one to assert the correct answer for maxNumber 999 is 233168. That way you're learning two things at once - how to solve the problems and how to verify your code with unit tests.

Answer (score -4):

You can do in single for loop as :

```
int total = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    total += i;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Note that the user is not asking for a complete solution.

Comment: You need to answer the question and only then offer a suggestion.